# Visual freeze during startup

Tags: 12.10, startup

Just upadted to 12.10 now it visually freezes with the load screen (Ubuntu with the red dots under it) the usual sound for the log-on screen is played and I can apparently log in but the screen image doesn't change.

Comment: With so little details its impossible to help you. Have a look at [ask] a question

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problem boot your ubuntu and when ubuntu logo and dots appeared on screen, press up or down arrow to see some details of booting. look for failed status and send back the result here.

Comment: Tried that more than a dozen times it didn't do anything other than for a moment I saw '^[A'. Instead I went into the grub startup menu and edited it to contain 'noquiet nosplash' and the only thing I am able to catch is four lines of 
'microcode: failed to load amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin'